how to remove all recipes from a mod for a specific minecraft player?
I'm will play 1.7.10 modded minecraft with my friends, and we will make a ALL vs ALL pvp server where each player have 3 personal mods that no one except he can use, we also have public mods that can be used by everyone
I'm trying to us craftweaker to remove all recipes from the mods that the player don't own
Here's my try on zencript:
import crafttweaker.player.IPlayer;

if(player.name != "mael_matos"){
     recipes.removeByMod("arsmagica2");
     recipes.removeByMod("DraconicEvolution");
     recipes.removeByMod("rftools");
} else if(player.name != "pegasus"){
     recipes.removeByMod("TConstruct");
     recipes.removeByMod("ProjectE");
     recipes.removeByMod("Mekanism");
} else if(player.name != "a"){
     recipes.removeByMod("AWWayofTime");
     recipes.removeByMod("EnderIO");
     recipes.removeByMod("InventoryPets");
} else if(player.name != "sr57"){
     recipes.removeByMod("witchery");
     recipes.removeByMod("blockarmor");
     recipes.removeByMod("vampirism");
} else if(player.name != "abner8388"){
     recipes.removeByMod("aether");
     recipes.removeByMod("legends");
     recipes.removeByMod("sus");
     recipes.removeByMod("magicalcrops");
}


i dont know how to ident code here,so a posted on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/y84MtWFz
